# Why is my SSMS default .mdf file folder is empty?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, mdf

Why is my default SSMS database .mdf file folder 'empty'?

I have searched for an answers for hours now and cannot find anything.

In SSMS, the properties of the database I am after says the file is at this path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

SSMS screenshot:
[image: SSMS properties screenshot]

Yet, when I navigate to that exact folder, it's empty? Screenshot below:

[image: File explorer screenshot, with folder properties]

Am I missing a permission?

Answer (score 1):

The folder isn't empty, you just don't have permissions to view the folder, and so when you get the properties of the folder you get information on what you can see: *nothing*.

If you try to actually open the folder and you have permission to elevate your permissions, you'll get the prompt to do so:

[image]

> #### You don't currently have permission to access this folder
>
> Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder.

If you then click Continue you'll be able to access the folder, and see that there are indeed files in said folder.

If you then went back to the parent folder and asked for the properties of the folder, you would see the size of the directory:

Before elevated permissions:
[image: Image showing the same as the OP's, where the Size is 0 bytes, and the Folder contains 0 Files, 0 Folders]

After elevated permissions:
[image: Image showing that the folder now is 165GB in Size, and contains 94 Files, 0 Folders.]

Comment: So my issue was indeed permissions (my account is an administrator), but your method did not solve it. I had to set SYSTEM as the file owner for the DATA folder and enable inheritance, then the files all popped up. Thanks for the assistance